# Using Java Immutables generated from a different package

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

I have a class in package `foo`, `FooImmutableCatUser` that wishes to use the Immutable, `ImmutableCat` object defined in package `bar`. However, I'm having issues getting `FooImmutableCatUser` in package `foo` to recognize `ImmutableCat` despite properly importing it. The import errors (unused import), and building yields the error: `error: cannot find symbol` at `ImmutableCat.of()`.

My directory structure in `bar` looks like:

```
\bar
  \models
     \Cat.java
```

Cat.java is defined as

```
package bar.models;
import org.immutables.value.Value;

@Value.Immutable
public interface Cat {
    String getName();
    Object getValue();
}
```

This correctly compiles to the `ImmutableCat` object.

I try to access this in `FooImmutableCatUser` like so:

`ImmutableCat.of("myString", myObject)`.

However, this throws the `error: cannot find symbol` above from both IntelliJ and Gradle.

I'm pretty sure I've seen code that uses Immutables from other packages before. How do you get gradle or IntelliJ to recognize Immutables from other packages while building? Is there a package dependency I need to list somewhere?

Edit: I have already tried enabling annotations with intellij via the [APT instructions from Immutable](https://immutables.github.io/apt.html). I've followed those instructions to the letter, but Immutables are still not recognized, possibly due to gradle and Intellij specifying different build output directories. Maybe that is the issue--I'll post back here if resolving that is actually the solution.

Comment: https://immutables.github.io/apt.html

Comment: Where does the exception come from? If it comes from IDEA, it may be because you have turned off APT in project configuration (see link above to find how to turn it on). If it comes from gradle builds, please show us your build configuration.

Comment: Yeah I have turned APT on (I did actually follow that configuration to the letter).